# When Value Get Updated In FireBase It Just Create New Item in Listview Instead Of Updating Value

Tags: firebase, listview

This Is My Code For MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference ref;
ArrayList<String> list;
ArrayAdapter <String> adapter;
User user;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    user = new User();

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = database.getReference("match1contest1");
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.user_info,R.id.userInfo, list);
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                user = ds.getValue(User.class);
                list.add(user.getName().toString()+user.getEmail().toString());

            }
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

This Is My User.class

public class User {

```
private String name;
private String email;
private String phone;
private String userName;
private String password;

public User() {
}

public User(String name, String email, String phone, String userName, String password) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

This is My activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView">
</ListView>
```

This is My user_info.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/userInfo"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Problem
When I Open My App I Works Well,Creates 3 items.
But When i Just Change any Value It Just Create 3 More Items Instead of Updating And when I restart my app then It Work Fine

Comment: You only have published the code to obtain the Firebase data, but not the code about the updates, and how your app creates new users. So I are not able to answer anything to help you.

Comment: I am not updating my data from app just changing manually

Comment: So is the problem in Firebase console web?

Comment: No in my android application.Can u plz tell me how can i upload images here

Comment: I don't understand you. You said you are not updating your data from the app, but later you answer the problem is in your app. Please be clear in order to obtain the best answer. You can edit your question and and images or more code, and specifying clear information about your problem.